# Multivariate distribution rewriting

Tags: probability

The usual form for a multivariate distribution is:$$p(\boldsymbol{x}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{D/2}|\boldsymbol{V}|^{1/2}} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu}) \right) \tag{1}$$

I have been told that one can write it in a more succint form:
$$p(\boldsymbol{x}) = \exp \left( \xi + \boldsymbol{\eta}^T\boldsymbol{x} -\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{\Lambda} \boldsymbol{x} \right) \tag{2}$$
where: $\Lambda=\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}$, $\boldsymbol{\eta}=\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}$, $\xi=-\frac{1}{2}(D \log 2\pi - \log |\boldsymbol{\Lambda}|+\boldsymbol{\eta}^T\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\eta})$.

By substituting these back into that shorter expression, I end up with this:
$$p(\boldsymbol{x}) = (2\pi)^{-D/2} |\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}|^{1/2} \exp \left(  -\frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{\mu}^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu} + \boldsymbol{\mu}^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x} - \frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x} \right) \tag{3}$$

Where I have used this result to arrive at the expression: $\boldsymbol{V}^T = \boldsymbol{V}$ and so $(\boldsymbol{V}^{-1})^T = (\boldsymbol{V}^T)^{-1} = \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}$. The expression that I arrive at is different from the original formulation of the multivariate gaussian. I think there is a missing term. If I look at the exponent part of the original expression, then this is what I should be getting right?:

$$-\frac{1}{2} (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1} (\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu}) = \frac{1}{2} (-\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}+\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu}^T \boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}) \tag{4}$$

> 1) And so I am missing a second term:
>   $\boldsymbol{x}^T\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu}$  from (4) in
>   (3). Correct?
>
> 2) Is this true: $|\boldsymbol{V}^{-1}|^{1/2}=|\boldsymbol{V}|^{-1/2}$

Comment: 2) is true as $\det(A^{-1})=1/\det(A)$, if $A\neq 0$.

Comment: Please check your post. I think the sign of $\log|\Lambda|$ in the $\xi$ expression should be a plus. Btw. it does not make sense to introduce $\Lambda=V^{-1}$ is is only introducing complexity without any reason.

Comment: It would be interesting to know why one would like to write it like this? It is a mess :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath to more easily express the product of N multivariate Gaussians apparently:)

Comment: To me, the first form is even easier for this purpose :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath oh boy... I'd love to see your work on this :) the only resource I found on Google that showed how to do it, is through this weird reformulation. I didn't Google well I guess..

Answer (score 1):

$$p(\mathbb{x}) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{D/2}|V|^{1/2}} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^T V^{-1}(x-\mu) \right)$$
$$=\exp\left({-\ln\left[(2\pi)^{D/2}|V|^{1/2}\right]}\right)\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2}(x^T-\mu^T) V^{-1}(x-\mu) \right)$$
$$=\exp\left(-D/2\ln(2\pi)-1/2\ln|V| -\frac{1}{2}(x^TV^{-1}-\mu^TV^{-1}) (x-\mu) \right) $$
$$=\exp\left(-D/2\ln(2\pi)-1/2\ln|V| -\frac{1}{2}(x^TV^{-1}x-\mu^TV^{-1}x-x^TV^{-1}\mu+\mu^TV^{-1}\mu) \right)  $$
$$ =\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(D\ln 2\pi+\ln|V| +x^TV^{-1}x-\mu^TV^{-1}x-x^TV^{-1}\mu+\mu^TV^{-1}\mu \right)\right] $$
$$ =\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(D\ln 2\pi+\ln|V|+\mu^TV^{-1}\mu -2\mu^TV^{-1}x+x^TV^{-1}x \right)\right] $$
$$ =\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(D\ln 2\pi+\ln|V|+\mu^TV^{-1}\mu\right)+\mu^TV^{-1}x-\frac{1}{2}x^TV^{-1}x \right] $$

Compare this with your given expression and you are done. Note that you might also need $\mu^TV^{-1}\mu=\mu^TVV^{-1}V^{-1}\mu=\mu^T(V^{-1})V^{-1}V^{-1}\mu=(V^{-T}\mu^T)V^{-1}V^{-1}\mu=(V^{-1}\mu^T)V^{-1}(V^{-1}\mu)$

Comment: hmm. this is what I am getting as well

Comment: It is precisely this last step that I am failing to execute... :)